# Bandsintown tour widget popup not to front

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I have implemented the [Bandsintown Tour Dates Widget](https://www.bandsintown.com/artist_platform/tour_dates_widget) in [this page](http://syncageband.com/tour.php), but when clicked on *RSVP* or the venue name, the Facebook popup will appear under the widget content, making it impossible to be clicked.

The code is the following:

```css
.content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: table;
 border-spacing: 10px;
}

#fullwidthcontent {
 z-index: -1;
 width: 75%;
 min-width: 600px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #000000;
 opacity: 0.7;
 height: 86%;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 210px;
 top: 15px; 
 overflow: auto;
}

.fullwidthoverlay {
 z-index:9999;
 width: 75%;
 min-width: 600px;
 height: 60%;
 opacity: 1;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 210px;
 top: 145px; 
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://widget.bandsintown.com/javascripts/bit_widget.js'
></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="content">

 <div class="fullwidthoverlay">
   <a href="http://www.bandsintown.com/Syncage" class="bit-widget-initializer" target="_blank" data-artist="Syncage" data-text-color="#FFFFFF" data-link-color="#FFFFFF" style="z-index:9999999;">Syncage Tour Dates</a>
    </div>
  <div class="column" id="fullwidthcontent"> 
  <h1>Tour</h1>
  </div>
 

</div>

</body>
```

Any idea on how to bring it to the front?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the z-index to 2 on the `fullwidthoverlay` class.

```
.fullwidthoverlay {
    z-index:2; /*<--- Here change it to 2 */
    width: 75%;
    min-width: 600px;
    height: 60%;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 210px;
    top: 145px; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: It does not change, unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: If I change that it does work at my end.  It is definately to do with your z-indexes in your CSS.  You need to use an inspector and see which z-index the overlay has and set that to be below that of the Facebook widget that gets loaded.

Comment: I am glad it's sorted.  If the issue is working correctly may I suggest that the question is marked as answered.